# VS Code showing *No module named 'ttkbootstrap'* even after successfully installing

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, tkinter

I am running tkinter on Vscode on windows OS but I can't import ttkbootstrap module, i have properly installed it but it shows module not found error. Please help anyone. there's nothing to help me. I am writing

import ttkbootstrap as ttk

Comment: Have the same problem.  I created a virtual environment using CTRL+SHIFT+P (Python 3.12.1), pip install ttkbootstrap -- and get Requirement already satisfied: ttkbootstrap /
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=8.2.0) if I attempt to reinstall -- and copied and pasted the first code from https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

This problem is usually caused by the incorrect Python environment.

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to change your python interpreter to the environment where you installed the python package.

I suggest you [creating virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment-in-the-terminal) which can make it easier to manage your Python package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
py -m pip install ttkbootstrap
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you created folder with name ttkbootstrap, just change the folder name, also do not use it for python file or you can name like this ttk_boot_strap.py.

I faced same problem and solved it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using Visual Code Studio. If you are installing inside the terminal in your environment try:

```
pip install ttkbootstrap
```

without the -m flag that is.